# How to convert Date and time to milliSeconds

Tags: android, datepicker, timepicker

i have done of getting and set date and time to my TextView, now i want to know "How to convert Date and time to milliSeconds when i select and set from DatePicker and TimePicker to TextView", help me with codes

my tried code,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView txtDateSet;
private TextView txtTimeSet;
int cDay, cMonth, cYear;
int tHours, tMinutes;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

    txtDateSet = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txt_date_display);
    txtTimeSet = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txt_time_display);

    txtDateSet.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            displayAlertDialog ();
        }
    });

}

public void displayAlertDialog () {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View layout = inflater.inflate (R.layout.custom_alert, (ViewGroup) findViewById (R.id.lnt_root));
    final DatePicker dateSet = (DatePicker) layout.findViewById (R.id.date_picker);
    final TimePicker timeSet = (TimePicker) layout.findViewById (R.id.time_picker);
    final TextView txtOk = (TextView) layout.findViewById (R.id.txt_ok);

    builder.setView (layout);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create ();
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside (true);
    alertDialog.show ();

    txtOk.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            cDay = dateSet.getDayOfMonth ();
            cMonth = dateSet.getMonth ();
            cYear = dateSet.getYear ();
            tHours = timeSet.getCurrentHour ();
            tMinutes = timeSet.getCurrentMinute ();

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, cYear);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cMonth);
            cal.set (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cDay);
            cal.set (Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tHours);
            cal.set (Calendar.MINUTE, tMinutes);

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy");
            String formatedDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime ());
            txtDateSet.setText (""+formatedDate);

            SimpleDateFormat stf = new SimpleDateFormat ("hh:mm aa");
            String formatedTime = stf.format (cal.getTime ());
            txtTimeSet.setText (""+formatedTime);

            alertDialog.dismiss ();
        }
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can Try follow code for getting miliseconds from Date.

```
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
            format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            Date date = format.parse(text);
            long millis = date.getTime();
```

and we also having one Standard Library Called [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) Which is Provide Lot's off functinality related with date time.using this library you can easily get Miliseconds from DateTime.
I am Also Having one Code Snippet Which is just return Miliseconds from DateTime.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                    .withLocale(Locale.US)
                    .withZoneUTC();


            DateTime datetime = formatter.parseDateTime(text);
            long millis = dateTime.getMillis();

            //Or
            //long millis = formatter.parseMillis(text);
```

I hope you are Clear with My Idea.

**Best of Luck**

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this,

```
  public String getDay(String str){
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("mon")
    return "Monday";
    ....
    }
```

as per your code

```
String mDate = dayFormat.format (cDay);
            StringBuilder dateBuilder = new StringBuilder ()
                    .append (getDay(mDate)).append (",")
                    .append (mMonth).append (" ")
                    .append (cDay).append (",")
                    .append (cYear);
```

OR

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM dd, YYYY");
```